# What causes a for loop to hang?

Tags: bash

I have a for loop that loops through the running of another script with different values for the `-c` flag. When I run it, it hangs and nothing happens.

When I run the `./executer.sh` command you see getting looped through by itself the for loop operates fine; However, when it is called in this new script so I can loop through it hangs instead of executed.

Hanging for loop:

```
while getopts "g:e:t:c:" arg;
do
  case "$arg" in
    t) IFS=',' read -r -a types <<< "$OPTARG";;
    e) env="$OPTARG";;
    c) IFS=',' read -r -a components <<< "$OPTARG";;
    g) SMODE=$OPTARG;;
  esac
done

for i in "${!components[@]}"
do
  if [ "$SMODE" = "start" ]; then
    r=$(./executer.sh -g $SMODE -t ${types[$i]} -c ${components[$i]} -e $env)
    echo "$r"
  else 
    echo "Not recognised"
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ case "$arg" in
+ SMODE=start
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ case "$arg" in
+ IFS=,
+ read -r -a types
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ case "$arg" in
+ IFS=,
+ read -r -a components
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ case "$arg" in
+ env=testing
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ for i in '"${!components[@]}"'
+ '[' start = start ']'
++ ./executer.sh -g start -t startingKit -c initialStart=1.2 -e testing
```

Command I run:

```
./executerApp.sh -g start -t startingKit -c initialStart=1.2 -e testing
```

Comment: Well, this is an infinite loop. What were you expecting?

Comment: Even with an ```else``` statement it is the same result?

Comment: After processing an argument with `getopts`, you have to issue `shift` commands to go to the next argument.

Comment: @PierreFrançois No, `getopts` does that for you. After you've finished processing, you should shift by `$((OPTIND-1))` to discard all options and a `--` sentinel, though.

Comment: @BenjaminW. So I need to put that after my while loop? How would it look in my script? Are you able to give an example?

Comment: Your trace doesn't match the command you claimed to run. The `=1.2` seems to have been stripped from the component.

Comment: The loop itself isn't hanging; `executer.sh` isn't completing.

Comment: [This](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/035#getopts) is a good example of `getopts` usage.

Comment: @chepner yes, it is supposed to be stripped and then the two are stored in two separate values in ```executer.sh``` and then used as arguments in subsequent functions. When I run ```executer.sh``` alone it works fine but when I try to run it in a loop to loop through different components it hangs.

Comment: @BenjaminW. it still doesn't function with adding ```shift "$((OPTIND-1))"```

Comment: @chepner well the idea is that this loop is just supposed to loop through the execution of the ```executer.sh``` script where the stripping takes place. Strips first component and uses in subsequent functions and commands, then strips second component and does the same and so on.

Comment: @chepner I made a mistake in question.. it should be ``` ++ ./executer.sh -g start -t startingKit -c initialStart=1.2 -e testing, ``` I have changed it now

Comment: What happens if you run the script without a command substitution; `r=$(foo); echo "$r"` is pretty much the same as `foo`, except `foo`'s standard output is different.

Comment: ```+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ case "$arg" in
+ SMODE=start
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ case "$arg" in
+ IFS=,
+ read -r -a types
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ case "$arg" in
+ IFS=,
+ read -r -a components
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ case "$arg" in
+ env=testing
+ getopts g:e:t:c: arg
+ shift 8
+ for i in '"${!components[@]}"'
+ '[' start = start ']'
++ foo
./executerApp.sh: line 22: foo: command not found
+ r=
+ echo ''
```   This is the output